# Catching Routed values in Mule 4

Tags: mule

How can i catch the routed values by choice connector in a variable.

condition am checking is below

vars.SplitName != vars.NameVar

I need the values which are routed by above condition.

Comment: The question is not quite clear. Please clarify exactly what you need. I'm not sure what 'routed values' means.

Comment: I am using choice connector to compare two varibales, values which are not equal will be routed in default path right? So i need to catch that values in a variable for processing. How can i achieve this?

Comment: default will be used if the conditions of each branch all evaluate to false. Do you want to catch the values of the variables, the conditions, or identify the branch executed in the choice? Please add an example to the question, to clarify it.

Comment: yes, i want to catch values passed through default in a variable. For example

{
    "name": "salesforce.com"
  }
if this values if sent to default how can i catch in variable ?

Comment: a variable lives in the event, and it will last only until the flow execution is complete. It looks like your question is how to cache or preserve a value, not related to the choice router. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, I need to catch the values which reach default path in choice connector and set them in variable